# Prove that the group of rigid motions of a cube contains 24 elements.

Tags: group-theory

How can I prove that the group of rigid motions of a cube contains 24 elements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: a cube has $6$ sides. If a particular side is facing upward, then there are four possible rotations of the cube that will preserve the upward-facing side. Hence, the order of the group is $6\times 4 = 24$.

Comment: Trying this approach with an icosahedron is a pretty fun exercise.